# Alert password field that stores password into the keychain and checks it against original login view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

This is what I would like to happen I have screwed this up 60 times over now.

Ok, I have a login View Controller that handles the login using the username and password and a remember me switch.  The login view controller verifies against an API, checks the credentials then proceeds. If the user has selected the remember me switch the password is stored. Next I have a separate deposit view controller.  Once the user clicks the deposit button within this deposit controller it pops up an alert with a password field and once the password is entered it checks against the original login screen password to see if they match if they do. It pushes on another view controller and then life goes on.  Otherwise if it doesnt match the stored pass and alert with and error is presented.

This just doesnt seem that hard but I'm having the hardest time with it I hope I made myself clear and questions let me know.

-Justin

Comment: What part are you hung up on?

Comment: Well the login works, but I cant store it to check against later.  Also, just storing in general in this framework is giving me fits.

Comment: So I guess to better answer that I need to store the value from the password field in alert from the deposit view controller.

Comment: Please update the question with the code that is giving you a problem. Is this a third party framework you're working with?

Comment: Yes mark its private can I PM you?

Comment: Im so new to stacks newbie question how do you PM on here?  Im starting to feel retarded.

Comment: Hahaha no need to worry. I don't think we can. If there is, I haven't found it either. Email me. You can find my address in my profile.

Comment: Mark, I know this sound double dumb but I searched you profile and I can't see anything.  Maybe cause Im new? email me if you could jundaj at gmail dot com

Answer (score 1):

In order to save text entered in a textField in an alertView, you have to store it in another variable before the alertView is dismissed.  I use `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` to store the variable, since that is called after editing is complete, but before the alertView is dismissed.

Hope this helps!